# Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такую обводку снизу

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как сделать такую линейную обводку снизу с отступами по бокам[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обычный градиент в псевдоэлементе ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: #1b1426;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.bank {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #272636;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

.bank::before,
.bank::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.bank::before {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #502651 0%, #533638 100%);
}

.bank::after {
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f32ebc 0%, #fb7f47 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bank">Банк</div>
```